# Bind click event to single select element on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple `select` elements. When one of them is changed I want to bind a click event only to its next element with the `.btn` class. This is my code:

```
<div class="whole">
    <ul>
        <li>
            first
            <select>
                <option></option>
                <option>reject</option>
                <option>hire</option>
            </select>
            <span class="btn">button</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            second
            <select>
                <option></option>
                <option>reject</option>
                <option>hire</option>
            </select>
            <span class="btn">button</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            third
            <select>
                <option></option>
                <option>reject</option>
                <option>hire</option>
            </select>
            <span class="btn">button</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
$('select').change(function() {
    var $changed = $(this);
    bindClick($changed);
});

var bindClick = function($el){
    $('.whole').on('click', $el.next(), function() {
        console.log('ciao');
    });
}
```

What happens is that after a `select` is changed click is bound on every `.btn` element. I am using jQuery. Here is an example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ciroxxx/ohnruubh/)

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Check http://api.jquery.com/on/ . You think you are using `.on( events [, selector ] , handler )` but you are in fact using `.on( events, [, data ], handler )` . Also, the selector must be a string or null. Not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second argument to [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) is considered as data not as a selector(selector should be a string)

The verison of `on` you are using the `$el.next()` value is considered as custom `data`(if the second argument is not a string) for the event and the event is bound to the `whole` element - does not use event delegation

Instead you can directly bind the handler to the `$el.next()` element

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var $changed = $(this);
  bindClick($changed);
});

var bindClick = function($el) {
  $el.next().on('click', function() {
    snippet.log('change: ' + this.innerText);
  });

  $('.whole').on('click', $el.next(), function(e) {
    snippet.log('whole click:' + e.data.text());
    console.log('event', e)
    console.log('data', e.data)
  });
}
```

```css
li {
  padding: 2em;
}
.btn {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<div class="whole">
  <ul>
    <li>first
      <select>
        <option></option>
        <option>reject</option>
        <option>hire</option>
      </select>
      <span class="btn">button 1</span>
    </li>
    <li>second
      <select>
        <option></option>
        <option>reject</option>
        <option>hire</option>
      </select>
      <span class="btn">button 2</span>
    </li>
    <li>third
      <select>
        <option></option>
        <option>reject</option>
        <option>hire</option>
      </select>
      <span class="btn">button 3</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: And if second argument is invalid, it is assigning event on the `parent` ? I guess so..

Comment: @RayonDabre  it will consider it as custom data and it will be available as `event.data` in the handler

Comment: Aah..Did not think of that.. _Good one!_ You should provide ref for `.on()`

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that the delegate signature of `on()` expects a string selector in the second property, not a jQuery object.

However you can improve the logic by using the `off()` method to remove any previously added click handlers and also by reducing any confusion the user may have by only displaying a button when it can be clicked. Try this:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $('.btn').off('click').removeClass('active');
    $(this).next('.btn').addClass('active').click(function() {
        console.log('ciao');
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ohnruubh/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohnruubh/3/)**

```
$('select').change(function() {
  var $changed = $(this);
  bindClick($changed.closest('li').next().find('select')); //pass the next select element
});

var bindClick = function($el){
    $el.on('click',function(){ // bind event directly to that element, without using event delagation
    console.log('ciao');
  });
}
```

Also the problem was you were passing a Jquery Object as your second parameter. it should be a string which represents a selector

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
[
$('select').change(function() {
    var $changed = $(this);
 bindClick($changed);
});
var bindClick = function($el){
$el.next().addClass('active')
$('.whole').off('click','.active')
    $('.whole').on('click','.active',function(){
    console.log('ciao');
  });
}
]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ohnruubh/5/

Comment: Your code works, but I didn't intend to use classes and you didn't explain why mine is not working. Thanks however